# Save Safari javascript console to file?

Tags: javascript, safari

Is it possible to save out the javascript console in Safari Web Inspector to a file?  I can't find any way to do it, and the only way to select all is to drag with the cursor (very difficult when I have a long continuous stream of log output).

Comment: Ctrl/Cmd + A? Simple enough for me.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for the Javascript console window.

Comment: So do this, click and hold on any text that is already there. Then click Cxx + A, while still holding your LMB. Voila!

Comment: Again, your suggestion works for a normal webpage.  But it does not work for the JS console output -- at least on Safari 6 on Lion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured something out:

While holding down SHIFT, select the start of the part you want.  Then release SHIFT and scroll down with the scrollbar.

Shift-click again on the end of the selection.  Then you can copy/paste as needed.

Comment: Does not work if you have muiltiple items in the log. Crap browser.

Comment: inf3mo, yes it does. I followed the steps starting with the first part of the first line then ended on the last part of the last line then copied. Everything pasted just fine.

Comment: has anyone found another way to do it more efficiently and less hacky? haha

Comment: @JonathanIshii `cmd+S` as mentioned above does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Click inside the console, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>. There is no step 3.

Note that this saves the output in plain text so there's no colorization, highlighted fields, etc.

Comment: much better then nothing, thanks mate, I had huge log where I was unable to search

Answer (score 0):

I can just use select all context menu after I clicked the gear icon to right of console tab in developer tools then unchecked "Wrap lines to editor width"
With this checked I could only copy first line, unchecked I could select all and copy/paste into a text file.